# How to tell if a user has updated a profile field in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to determine how in drupal 7 I can programmatically tell if a user has updated a custom field in their profile within the past 24 hours however looking through the tables I can't seem to find any field with that information does anyone have any ideas?? Essentially I need to pull this information out during a batch job that run onces a night and updates other systems based upon the information in drupal. If someone can think of a better way todo this it would be appreciated. thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i dont know if its working or not try the following steps

1- first you should tell drupal....when user edit the profile page do something...(whatever the something is ..insert something to database..retrieve something..etc)

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter
*/
function newcontent_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
    $form['#submit'][]  = '_do_something_when_user_save_profile';   
}    
}   


/**
* do something when user save profile
*/
function _do_something_when_user_save_profile($form,$form_state){
// do something
}
```

now i think we need to do some queries ... first we need to create 2 tables
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7
(this url will help you to create your schema)

- the first table will contain the current value of the field u want track so i think this table should have the following fields
  (primary key , user id, field name, field value)
- the second table will contain the date of the last upated operation the user made
  i think the fields will be like the following (primary key,user id , field name, date)

now lets return to the form submit function

```
/**
* do something when user save profile
*/
function _do_something_when_user_save_profile($form,$form_state){
   // now i can check in the first table to see
       // is the current submitted value for this field = the value in the table
       // if its = the table value then the user didn't change any thing now i dont 
       // need to update the second table
       // if the current submitted value != the value in the table then its mean
       // that the user have updated this field ... 
       // now i should insert new value to the second 
       // table with the current date time and the current field value
}
```

i hope u under stand me and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

maged adel provided reasonable solution, however there is one more way of doing this:
you can use [hook_user_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) for this purpose. It's better that solution provided above because of 2 reasons:
1) you have both $edit - entered values and $account - user account values, so you can compare and get know what fields being updated (if you don't have 1 specific field to check).
2) just 1 hook to implement.

Comment: hi 32i, i have used this function. But table ( user_changes)  is not getting updated.  function bartik_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
 db_insert('user_changes')->fields(array(
 'uid' => $account->uid,
 'changed' => time(),
 ))->execute();
 
}